# Send mails with Python and an IMAP/SMTP Server

Tags: python, email, python-2.6, smtplib, imaplib

i have a couple issues with sending Email with Python using my own SMTP/IMAP Server.
Here's the code :

```
import sys
import imaplib
import smtplib
import email
import email.header
import datetime

smtp_session = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server)
try:
    smtp_session.ehlo()
except :
    err = sys.exc_info()[0]


message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s""" % (email_from, ", ".join([email_to]), "subject", "body")
try:
    smtp_session.sendmail(email_from, [email_to], message)
    smtp_session.quit()
except:
    err = sys.exc_info()[0]

if err != "" or err !=None:
    NagiosCode = 2
    NagiosMsg = "CRITICAL: Script execution failed : " + str(err)
```

Ok so for the two issues i have: 
When i send a mail from my script i need the mail to appear in the "sent items" diretory of my mail box who send it.

Second issue i have : When sending my mail i catch this exception :

```
<class 'smtplib.SMTPException'>
```

EDIT : Exception trace :

```
  File "checkIMAP_client.py", line 153, in <module>
    smtp_session.login(login, password)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 559, in login
    raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

EDIT : 
It seems my SMTP server doesn't require authentification.
But the program still returns me an empty exception.

Code is updated.

Comment: Unless your SMTP server does it for you, you need to connect to your IMAP server and "STORE" the email in the sent folder for your account. As for the immediate exception you're receiving - what else is that expection telling you - there should be a description or error number to indicate what the specific problem is - try not catching the exception and just let it stop the program...

Comment: I added the trace.
Regarding the IMAP part, how to do that ?
By the way i might need to delete these emails with Python, i couldn't find how to do that in IMAPlib python documentation.

Comment: For the IMAP bit - you've got a nice bit of reading of [RFC 3501](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501)... - check out the STORE command.

Comment: Regarding the AUTH error: try `.starttls` followed by `.ehlo` before login. The authentication is normally allowed over an encrypted channel only.

Comment: I hadn't any auth method set on my SMTP server. I removed everything about auth in my code. Thank your for the idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So for the two issues i had, i found the answers thanks to the above comments :

Putting my sent e-mail via SMTP in the right mailbox in the Sent directory :
https://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/
Look for "Uploading messages"

Exception issue :
I had no auth methods set on my SMTP server.